# 英名の月を含む日付の文字列変換について

Tags: python3

pythonで英名の月を含む日付の文字列変換について伺いたいです。

```
date：10OCT2017
```

これが文字型なので日付型に変換したいです。

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime('date','%d%b%Y')
```

で変換を試みているのですが、エラーでできません。

どなたかご教示いただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

手元のPython 3.6.1環境では、下記のコーディングでうまく動作するようです。

`datetime.strptime('date','%d%b%Y')`の第一引数が本当に`'date'`のままだと、変数ではなく「date」という文字列扱いになります。
もしくは提示されたコードの`：`が全角文字なので、こちらを半角文字と間違えていないでしょうか。
下記のコードで解決しない場合、エラーをそのまま追記していただくとより詳細な回答を得やすいです。

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> date = "10OCT2017"
>>> datetime.strptime(date,'%d%b%Y')
datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 10, 0, 0)
>>> date = "date：10OCT2017"
>>> datetime.strptime(date,'date：%d%b%Y')
datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 10, 0, 0)
```